# Deserialization is not happening for 'Any' class for code generated by Swagger Codegen (Springboot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger-codegen

'**Any**' is supposed to hold a generic object which isn't of any fixed type. Defined as `Any:{}` in swagger spec , It isn't able to deserialize any information when provided with a JSON in a POST request.

Comment: please provide your sample code.

Comment: I'm using swagger codegen to create a server which is based on Open API specification. Which part of the code do you want to see? Any.class does not have any variables or code.